# How to assign the date array variable in ansible playbook using loop

Tags: ansible

I want to iterate the date values and increment by one when the loop performs in Ansible playbook.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    - command: date -d "+{{ item }} days"
      register: dates
      with_sequence: start=0 end=10
    - debug: msg="{{ dates.results | json_query('[].stdout') }}"
```

Comment: Yes .. but the date is not incremented as per the above program. Just we need to set the date as '12/18/2018' and add the date by one till the loop ends. Currently it is being displayed as below.                                                                                  changed: [localhost] => (item=1)